# Trying to setup a folder as network drive

Tags: networking, mount

I'm trying to setup a folder as a network drive.

I added the following into `/etc/fstab`:

```
//192.168.0.150/Files /media/sda1/Files cifs defaults,username=<name>,password=<password>
```

Then I tried `mount -a` to mount it (as the tutorial I'm using explained) but I got the following error message:

```
root@pi:/media/sda1# mount -a
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on //192.168.0.150/Files,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error
   (for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might
   need a /sbin/mount.<type> helper program)

   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail or so.
root@pi:/media/sda1#  dmesg | tail
[   43.233536] eth0: no IPv6 routers present
[   56.788933] ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
[   59.084915] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
[1208037.847633] CIFS VFS: Connecting to DFS root not implemented yet
[1208037.859146] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -22
[1208150.427065] Installing knfsd (copyright (C) 1996     okir@monad.swb.de).
[1208223.167024] CIFS VFS: Connecting to DFS root not implemented yet
[1208223.178430] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -22
[1208571.347110] CIFS VFS: Connecting to DFS root not implemented yet
[1208571.358562] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -22
```

Answer (score 1):

The only package required for a Samba client is cifs-utils.

Instead of putting the password in a publicly-viewable file, I would put it in a place that only the root can view.

**/etc/fstab entry:**

```
//192.168.0.150/Files /media/sda1/Files cifs auto,owner,rw,credentials=/root/samba.credentials 0 0
```

**/root/samba.credentials:**

```
username=u
password=p
```

You can improve this further by putting the Samba host name in /etc/hosts and specify the host name in fstab instead of the IP address.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you have the `smbfs` package installed - that will provide the `mount.cifs` command which will probably be stored in `/sbin` or `/usr/sbin`. I'd also recommend "**R**eading **T**he **F**ine **M**anual" i.e. look at the output from `man mount.cifs` as that points out that leaving the password in the `/etc/fstab` file is not secure!  Also, I hope the line in that file is not *literally*:

```
//192.168.0.150/Files /media/sda1/Files cifs defaults,username=<name>,password=<password>
```

in which the name you specify is "<name>" and the password "<password>" ?

Finally, have you set up your systems so that the  server is definately at 192.168.0.150?  Many people will direct you to set a static IP address on the Server but a more robust and elegant method to ensure this is to make your DHCP server (often your Broadband Modem/Router) reserve the required IP Address for the relevant MAC for the network interface on the Server that will be used to provide the share...